# Determine resolvent set of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

We consider $X=l^p(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$ for $1\leq p\leq\infty$ and define $T((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}})= (a_n x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} :=(\frac{1}{n^2+1}x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. (Btw: Compactness of this operator is shown in a last post, see: [Showing compactness of operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196483/showing-compactness-of-operator)).
Now I want to determine the resolvent set of $T$. This is the set of complex numbers $z$ for which $T-z1$ is invertible. I do not have an idea how to find this set. Are there any criteria/theorems/equivalences which I do not know yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the set $A=\{\frac{1}{n^2+1}:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is in the spectrum of $T$, because the canonical basis vectors $e_n$ and $e_{-n}$ are in $\ker\left(T-\frac{1}{n^2+1}I\right)$.  And of course, $0$ is in the spectrum since the operator is compact.  Now we need to show that these are the only members of the spectrum.  So suppose $z\in\mathbb C$ is nonzero and $z\notin A$. Then the map
$$S_z(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n^2+1}-z}x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$$
is bounded, and $(T-zI)S_z=S_z(T-zI)=I$.

Thus the spectrum of $T$ is $A\cup\{0\}$, and therefore the resolvent set is $\mathbb C\setminus(A\cup\{0\}) $.

---

To see that $S_z$ is bounded, observe that $A\cup\{0\}$ is closed.  Since $z\notin A\cup\{0\}$, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|z-x|\geq \varepsilon$ for all $x\in A\cup\{0\}$, and thus 
$$\|S_z(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}\|=\left\|\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n^2+1}-z}x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb Z}\right\|\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\|(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}\|.$$
Hence $\|S_z\|\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, so $S_z$ is bounded.

Comment: could you please something more to your steps concerning that these are the only members of the spectrum? especially why bounded? and what gives me the boundedness?

Comment: @tubmaster I editted to include an explanation for why $S$ is bounded.  Does that help?

Comment: ok thanks a lot but why do we need $S$ to be bounded?

Comment: @tubmaster The resolvent set of $T$ is the set of $z\in\mathbb C$ for which $T-zI$ has a bounded inverse.

Comment: why does the inverse have to be bounded? is it definition?

Comment: @tubmaster That's just the definition of the resolvent.  We're considering the algebra of bounded operators on a Banach space, and the resolvent of $T$ gives us scalars $z$ for which $T-zI$ has an inverse **in** the algebra of bounded operators.